# Error Connecting Raspberry 4 model B to Windows 10 Directly with ethernet cable

Tags: raspbian, connection, windows-iot

I received my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B yesterday installed latest Raspberry OS on MicroSD and have been trying to connect it to Windows 10 directly with a Ethernet cable "no hub or router" and I can not seem to PING or SSH successfully.

Have changed the `cmdline.txt` to the following

```
console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=2b5d3598-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes ip=192.168.1.1 rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
```

Set Windows 10 to the following:

```
IP Address -> 192.168.1.2

Subnet Mask -> 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway -> 192.168.1.1 (Same as Pi 4)

Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8
```

I have no external screen or peripherals. Using a Dell Laptop. This should not be rocket science, but not freaking working.

Please advise!

Thanks, Diego :oops:

Comment: Try `ip=192.168.1.1::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off`

Comment: thanks the ping worked, was reading raspberry pi docs, and port 22 is closed, is there a why to enable SSH:22 via the cmdline.txt or any other method? thanks

Comment: If you place a file called `ssh` (or `ssh.txt` should also work) on the boot partition (the only partition you can see on Windows when you plug a Pi's SD card in) on the next boot it will enable SSH.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-connect-two-computers-with-an-Ethernet-cable I hope this wll do the job.
The Rasp4 properties is different and i d't no how.to fix that.
Succes !!
jan